# Задание контента балуна

Tags: yandex-maps-api

Каким образом можно задать в качестве контента балуна строку с координатами точки? Речь идет о функции определения адреса клика на карте с помощью обратного геокодирования - https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/event_reverse_geocode

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если брать пример, который вы предоставили, то вот так:

```
balloonContent: firstGeoObject.geometry.getCoordinates()
```

https://jsfiddle.net/6nkvb9gf/

Comment: Благодарю, все получилось